# Implementing 'belongs' with LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, belongs-to

I have a List with the numbers (5,9,3) in it. Let's call it MyList

I would like to perform

```
var results = from a in myEntities.thing1 where a.ID belongsto MyList select a;
```

right now I do

```
List<T> t = new List<T>(); //I actually define T to a strong type

foreach (int i in MyList)
{
t.add(from a in myEntities.thing1 where a.ID==i select a);
}
```

I'm sure there must be a better way, but I can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var results = from a in myEntities.thing1 where MyList.Contains(a) select a;
```

Comment: There is a trick there for LINQ2SQL,  the "MyList" must be strong type reference to a "List<>" or an "array".

If you pass a "IList" the linq2sql will failed to compile